# Security of using .bpl as external modules

Tags: delphi, bpl

I'm still new with delphi and I developed an application that loads at runtime bpl files following this guide http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27178

The bpl files will be in the same folder as the main app, and I was wondering what is the security in doing this?

I found this question [External modules security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142303/external-modules-security) but it doesn't fully answers mine.

I mean, if the clients copy these bpl files and give them to other developers, can they use/access them if they have the same delphi version? Or in some ways access the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just executable modules like .exe or .dll modules. They are exactly as secure as any other executable module.

> If the clients copy these bpl files and give them to other developers, can they use/access them if they have the same delphi version?

Yes.

> Or in some ways access the source code?

No. Compiled bpl package files do not contain source code.

Comment: Although a developer *could* use a BPL, its usefulness would be severely hampered by the lack of associated DCU and DCP files.